how to create a dependent drop-down list linked to a multi selection source cell
I have dependent drop-down lists in sheet 1, P1 (the source cell) and Q1 (the dependent cell).
I used the following equation in data validation source for Q cell which worked great.
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(P7," ",""),DROPDOWN_LISTS!$L$1:$M$6,2,0))

Note: I arranged the data structure for this dependent cell in DROPDOWN_LISTS sheet. (Not the Problem)
I used a vba code to apply multi-selection options for cell P1, and these selections will be separated by a comma. The above equation works great if i choose only one option in cell P1, and if i choose many options in cell P1, the dependent cell Q1 doesn't work (for sure because P1 becomes has unfamiliar content)
The question, is there any solution for this case, so i can use both the multi-selection option in cell P1 and P2 showing the dependent lists for all selections in P1?
I searched a lot for this case but i didn't find any soluation suiting me.
